# Could rounding error occurs in the addition between float and an associative addition of integer?

Tags: floating-point, rounding-error, associativity

(1) I understand that integer addition is associative, for example (res1 & res always produce the same result)

```
int i1, i2, i3;
int res1 = i1 + i2 + i3;
int res2 = i1 + (i2 + i3);
```

(2) I also understand that rounding error may occur in the following case

```
float f = ...;
int   i1, i2, i3;
float res = f + i1 + i2 + i3 ; // rounding error may occur in `float + int`
```

(**Question**) What I want to know is, in the following code, could res1 & res2 always produce the same result (no rounding error)?

```
float f = ...;
int   i1, i2, i3;
float res1 = f + i1 + i2 + i3;
float res2 = f + (i1 + i2 + i3); // use associativity of integer addition
```

Comment: `i1 + i2 + i3` and `i1 + (i2 + i3)` may produce different results if there is overflow. E.g., `INT_MAX + 1 + -1` might trap whereas `INT_MAX + (1 + -1)` would not.

Comment: Tried, both produce 2147483647 (INT_MAX).

Comment: They both produced `INT_MAX` in **your** C implementation in the **one** example or few examples you tested. The C standard does not define the behavior of integer overflow. In a C implementation that traps overflow, the first will overflow and the second will not. In a C implementation where the expressions are used as part of a loop control test, the optimizer may treat the first as if it never occurs (creating an assumption that the variables never taken on these values, which can cause cascading effects in optimization) whereas it will not do that for the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    float f = 0x1p25f;
    int i1 = 1, i2 = 1, i3 = 1;
    printf("%.99g\n", f + i1 + i2 + i3);
    printf("%.99g\n", f + (i1 + i2 + i3));
}
```

prints:

```
33554432
33554436
```

when `float` is IEEE-754 binary32 and round-to-nearest is used.

On the other end, this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    float f = 0x1p-24f;
    int i1 = 1, i2 = -1, i3 = 0;
    printf("%.99g\n", f + i1 + i2 + i3);
    printf("%.99g\n", f + (i1 + i2 + i3));
}
```

prints:

```
0
5.9604644775390625e-08
```